# C++ Template Metafunction

Tags: c++, templates, winapi, c++14, template-meta-programming

I'm developing a wrapper over the SQL ODBC API for Win32, and it's quite frequent to have several functions like `GetXXXTextA` and `GetXXXTextW`. I wat to select the appropriate `GetA` or `GetW` depending on the user input type. I tried this:

```
// test getterA
int _stdcall pruebaA (int, char*, const char*)
{ return 0; }
// test getterW
int _stdcall pruebaW(int, wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)
{ return 0; }
template<typename T>
struct only_char_or_wchar_t
{
    using ct = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, char>::value || std::is_same<T, wchar_t>::value, T>;
};

template<typename char_type> struct char_or_wchart_api: only_char_or_wchar_t<char_type>
{
    constexpr static std::conditional_t<std::is_same<char_type, wchar_t>::value, int (_stdcall*)(int, wchar_t*, const wchar_t*) , int(_stdcall*)(int, char*, const char*)> prueba =
        std::is_same<char_type, wchar_t>::value
        ?
        ::pruebaW :
        ::pruebaA;
};

int main () {
    auto p2 = char_or_wchart_api<wchar_t>::prueba;
    p2(0, nullptr, L"");
    return 0;
}
```

But, Visual Studio 2017 keeps complaining (at line "`::pruebaA;`"):

`Error C2446: ':': no conversion from 'int (__stdcall *)(int,char *,const char *)' to 'int (__stdcall *)(int,wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)'`

Even though intellisense resolves correctly when "calling" `p2(.....)`  to `(int, wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)`

Do you have any idea what could be wrong about this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained by Klaus (and Justin, and R Sahu) your ternary operator receive two incompatible object.

But, if you use template specialization, you don't need `only_char_or_wchar_t` and (maybe using `auto` for the type) all became simpler

```
template <typename>
struct char_or_wchart_api;

template <>
struct char_or_wchart_api<char>
 { static constexpr auto prueba = ::pruebaA; };

template <>
struct char_or_wchart_api<wchar_t>
 { static constexpr auto prueba = ::pruebaW; };
```

But the better solution (IMHO) is the one proposed by Justin (and Klaus, point (2)): two functions with the same name; the arguments selecting the correct one.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, I didn't know about the restriction of the ternary operator. In fact, I made a mistake on my example, it would change the conditions of my question because `pruebaA` and `pruebaW` both have the same prototype, that's why I can't let the compiler choose by argument deduction.

Comment: @yo_gdg - yes... if `pruebaA()` and `pruebaW()` have the same signature... the problem change completely and simple overloading doesn't work. But, at this point, ternary operator should work...

Answer (score 6):

Notice that `pruebaA` and `pruebaW` have different types:

```
int _stdcall pruebaA(int, char*, const char*)
int _stdcall pruebaW(int, wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)
```

The first function takes different argument types from the second, thus the two function types are incompatible. You cannot return pointers to both of them from a ternary, as both types in a ternary must be compatible.

---

However, you are overcomplicating this. Just write an overloaded function:

```
// Choose better names for the arguments
int prueba(int arg1, char* arg2, const char* arg3) {
    return pruebaA(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

int prueba(int arg1, wchar_t* arg2, const wchar_t* arg3) {
    return pruebaW(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

This also simplifies the usage, as you only have to write `prueba(0, nullptr, L"")`, instead of having to specify which function you want to call.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have a lot wrong assumptions!

1) A conditional / ternary operator can not have two different return types. As this both expressions must be the same type or must be able to implicit cast to the first one!

2) If the type of your expression is clear at compile time, you do not need a manually selection of the function which shall be called. That is done from the compiler! A simple overload works perfect for that situation. No template needed at all and no SFINAE or constexpr if.

3) if you have user input, you can not decide with constexpr/std::is_same, because all template parameters must be known at compile time. You can not put run time data into template arguments!

As this, there must be a totally different solution for you problem!

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any idea what could be wrong about this code?

The problem is caused by the conditional expression when defining `pruebaA`.

The second and third items of a conditional expression cannot be totally unrelated.

E.g.

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

bool v = true;
(v ? A() : B());
```

will result in the same compiler error since nether `A` is convertible to `B` nor `B` is convertible to `A`.

In your case, the two types that are posing the problem are `int (__stdcall *)(int,char *,const char *)` and `int (__stdcall *)(int,wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)`.

You can use another metafunction to help with your intent.

```
template <typename T> struct func_selector;

template <> struct func_selector<char>
{
   using type = int(*)(int, char*, const char*);
   constexpr static type get() { return pruebaA; }
};

template <> struct func_selector<wchar_t>
{
   using type = int(*)(int, wchar_t*, const wchar_t*);
   constexpr static type get() { return pruebaW; }
};
```

and use

```
template<typename char_type> struct char_or_wchart_api: only_char_or_wchar_t<char_type>
{
   constexpr static auto prueba = func_selector<char_type>::get();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced you need something so ridiculous, and could probably just overload one function to take care of this:

```
char* GetXXXTextA(char*);
wchar_t* GetXXXTextW(wchar_t*);

// your overloads, same name
char*    GetXXXText(char* arg) { return GetXXXTextA(arg); }
wchar_t* GetXXXText(wchar_t* arg) { return GetXXXTextW(arg);
```

---

**If you insist on TMP** the problem is with the ternary, the last two operands must be convertible to the same type. For a much simpler example consider [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SdLVnW5qHJTFcbP6):

```
#include <type_traits>
struct A { };
struct B { };

int main() {
  auto result = std::is_same<int, int>{} ? A{} : B{};
}
```

Although one can clearly see at compile time this would be like having `A result = A{}`, it's not valid because `A` and `B` aren't compatible.

There are different ways around this, for C++11, you can use [tag dispatching](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c7youUDbsL8UBGHt) to choose an overload at compile time:

```
struct A { };
struct B { };

A f(std::true_type) {
  return {};
}

B f(std::false_type) {
  return {};
}

int main() {
  auto result = f(std::is_same<int, int>{});
}
```

For C++17 you can use [`if constexpr`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yUChJfjQwEIqKNt8):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A { };
struct B { };

auto f() {
  if constexpr (std::is_same<int, int>{}) {
    return A{};
  } else {
    return B{};
  }
}

int main() {
  auto result = f();
}
```

Comment: What is the use case here? If having already different types, I can use a simple overload, no tag dispatching needed. Getting a third type for tagging depends on the same root data type, so I can't the see benefit here.

Comment: @Klaus I'm not recommending it, but OP is trying to flex some TMP muscle even if it's unnecessarily complex so I'm just showing the technique they are actually looking for.